# Linking ID with Username in IF-statement

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, html-table

I've came a long part on the road with a project I'm working on. However I can't seem to get it working.

The script is rather "simple" but I'm not able to get it the way I want.
I am listing an inbox where I can see my messages sent and my messages received, however these are ID's and not Usernames, which I want to link the ID's to the Username in another table.

So let's say I'm ID 42 username = Moominen
and the receiver is ID 50 username = turtle

TABLE messages

```
sent_to|sent_by|message|sent_time
  42   |  50   | ....  | .....
  50   |  42   | ....  | .....
```

TABLE members

```
Memberid|Username|profilepic|
  42    |moominen|img.png   |
  50    |turtle  |turtle.png|
```

So I have got almost everything working except my IF-statement which changes the SQL-query.

```
$querysent = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sent_by=".$logged." or sent_to=".$logged.")                   ORDER BY sent_time desc";
$sqlsent = mysqli_query($dbc,$querysent) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
echo '<h3>Messages</h3>';
while($fetchsent = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlsent)) {
if ($fetchsent["sent_by"] == $logged) {
    $query = "SELECT Memberid, Username, profilepic FROM members WHERE Memberid=$logged LIMIT 1";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT Memberid, Username, profilepic FROM members WHERE Memberid=".$fetchsent["sent_by"]." LIMIT 1";
}

$sql = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

echo '<table class="table-condensed">
    <th>Sent by</th><th>Sent To</th><th>Message</th><th>Time</th>';
echo ('<tr><td><a href="index.php?page=profile&id='.$fetchsent["sent_by"].'">'.$fetch["Username"].'</a></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?page=profile&id='.$fetchsent["sent_to"].'">'.$fetch["Username"].'</td>
    <td>'.$fetchsent["message"].'</td>
    <td><abbr class="postdate" title="'.$fetchsent["sent_time"].'"></a></td>

    ');
echo ('</tr>');
echo '</table>';
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the Username linked to the corresponding ID in the table.

Comment: You need to use a `JOIN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off to use an `INNER JOIN` - this will return all the fields from both sets of tables where there is a match. If you wanted to grab all the results from `messages` even when there isn't a matching result in the `members` table, you would use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Here's how you would change your query:

```
$querysent = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sent_by=".$logged." or sent_to=".$logged.") ORDER BY sent_time desc";
```

Would change to:

```
$querysent = 
"SELECT m.*, mm.Memberid as Memberid_from, mm.Username as Username_from, mm.profilepic as profilepic_from, mmm.Memberid as Memberid_to, mmm.Username as Username_to, mmm.profilepic as profilepic_to 
FROM messages m 
INNER JOIN members mm ON mm.Memberid=m.sent_by 
INNER JOIN members mmm ON mmm.Memberid=m.sent_to 
WHERE (m.sent_by=".$logged." or m.sent_to=".$logged.") ORDER BY m.sent_time desc";
```

You should now use `$fetchsent["Username_from"]` to get the sent_by and `$fetchsent["Username_to"]` to get the sent_to

If you would like to know more about JOINS, check out the documentation on it:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

**Side Note**
I would highly recommend switching to PDO - prepared statements will take care of protecting you against SQL Injections among other things.

Comment: If I use the SQL you sent I still would have needed to split the Usernames

    `$querysent = "SELECT m.*, mm.Memberid, mm.Username, mm.profilepic FROM messages m INNER JOIN members mm ON mm.Memberid=m.sent_by WHERE (m.sent_by=".$logged." or m.sent_to=".$logged.") ORDER BY m.sent_time desc";
    <a href="index.php?page=profile&id='.$fetchsent["sent_by"].'">'.$fetchsent["sent_by"].'</a>
<a href="index.php?page=profile&id='.$fetchsent["sent_to"].'">'.$fetchsent["Username"].'</a>`
It will always take the first Username and display it on both TD's

Comment: You can do a double inner join on the table, I'll update my answer

Comment: ,thanks, that would be awesome.
I will go to PDO later on when I'm done with this small script.

Comment: thank you so much. That worked like a charm, all love to you!